# How to change an instance of a class into an instance of a subclass

Tags: c++, polymorphism, subclass

Basically what I am trying to do is set an instance of class 'MovingHero' into a 'ShootingHero', which is a subclass of 'MovingHero'.

As I have it now, the MovingHero class has a function called levelUp() that looks like this:

```
MovingHero levelUp()
{
    ShootingHero theHero();
    return theHero;
}
```

and in my main function I have:

```
if(hero1.getScore() == 5)
   hero1 = hero1.levelUp();
```

I'm not getting any errors, but after the if statement executes, hero1 is still a MovingHero rather than a ShootingHero.

I think this has something to do with operator overloading but I'm just not sure. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You might also consider using some useful pattern, like [Typed Object](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/type-object.html).

Comment: Is this really your code? Because `ShootingHero theHero();` is a function declaration, not a variable definition.

Comment: @Fred I already covered that in my answer, several minutes ago.

Comment: @FredOverflow Ah, most vexing parse! Didn't even catch that.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: I find that to be something of a misnomer in cases like this. I mean, it's not all that vexing! It's vexing when you want to pass a temporary as constructor argument: `ShootingHero theHero(HeroMagicType());`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, I didn't catch that. In that case, you can have my Internet points, of course. Do you accept PayPal?

Comment: This requires the derived class from `levelUp()` to be included in the parent class, a quite unusual and tricky ordeal.

Comment: @FredOverflow: It's okay — I will just steal some of your sweet repz ;)

Answer (score 3):

Operator overloading?! No, it has nothing to do with that.

When you return from that function, you *slice* your `ShootingHero` object<sup>†</sup> into a new `MovingHero`. In order to take advantage of dynamic polymorphism, you need to employ indirection. That means *pointers* and/or *references*.

You can't use object copying and keep the original most-derived type: your assumption that you have a `MovingHero` to work with is incorrect. Please read the chapter in your C++ book about polymorphism.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> Actually, you *don't* have a `ShootingHero` object, because you wrote `ShootingHero theHero();` which is a function declaration. The code you showed us will *not* compile; you probably meant `ShootingHero theHero;`.</sup>

Comment: He is likely coming from a Java/C# background where this would work better.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: He should try coming at it from a "reading my C++ book" background

Answer (score 2):

Polymorphism only works with pointers (and technically references, although this isn't as common). `MovingHero` and `ShootingHero` are two different types; there is no way to successfully assign objects of one type to another.

`MovingHero*` and `ShootingHero*` however are both essentially the same type (a pointer) differing only in the type of data the point to (which has no effect on the actual pointer (it just provides the compiler with information regarding what is considered "legal")), so you can successfully assign pointers to `ShootingHero` objects to pointers to `MovingHero` objects.

Indeed, you can always assign pointers of any type to pointers of any other type using a cast, although this will more often than not lead to garbage values when you dereference the pointers. However, polymorphism guantees that the conversion will be valid, so there is no need for a cast.

Using polymorphism, your function could be written:

```
MovingHero* levelUp()
{
    ShootingHero* theHero = new ShootingHero();
    return theHero;
}
```

Note that you must manually delete this pointer at some point, as it is dynamically allocated.

Comment: `Polymorphism applies only to pointers.` Not so. Polymorphism is a fundamental fact of C++ objects with virtual functions, but since copying performs slicing, you can only make use of it with pointers _or references_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Rephrased. Thanks for the suggestion.